# using variables in gsub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have a variable `address` which for now is a long string containing some unneccessary info, eg: `"Aboriginal Relations 11th Floor Commerce Place 10155 102 Street Edmonton AB T5J 4G8 Phone 780 427-9658 Fax 780 644-4939 Email gerry.kushlyk@gov.ab.ca"`

`Aboriginal Relations` is in a variable called `title`, and I'm trying to call `address.gsub!(title,'')`, but its returning the original string.

I've also tried `address.gsub!(/#{title}/,'')` and `address.gsub!("#{title}",'')` but those won't work either. Any ideas?

Sorry, the typo occurred when I typed it into stack overflow, heres the code and the output, copied and pasted:

(this is within a loop, so there will be multiple outputs)

```
p title
address.gsub!(title,'')
p address
```

output

```
"Aboriginal Relations "
"Aboriginal Relations 11th Floor Commerce Place 10155 102 Street Edmonton AB T5J 4G8 Phone         780 427-9658 Fax 780 644-4939 Email gerry.kushlyk@gov.ab.ca"
"Aboriginal Tourism Advisory Council "
"Aboriginal Tourism Advisory Council 5th Floor Terrace Building 9515 107 Street Edmonton AB T5K 2C3 Phone 780 427-9687 Fax 780 422-7235 Email foip.fintprccs@gov.ab.ca"
"Acadia Foundation "
"Acadia Foundation PO Box 96 Oyen AB T0J 2J0 Phone 403 664-3384 Fax 403 664-3316 Email acadiafoundation@telus.net"
"Access Advisory Council "
"Access Advisory Council 12th Floor Centre West Building 10035 108 Street Edmonton AB T5J 3E1 Phone 780 427-2805 Fax 780 422-3204 Email barb.joyner@gov.ab.ca"
"ACCM Benevolent Association "
"ACCM Benevolent Association Suite 100 9403 95 Avenue Edmonton AB T6C 4M7 Phone 780 468-4648 Fax 780 468-4648 Email accmmanor@shaw.ca"
"Acme Municipal Library "
"Acme Municipal Library PO Box 326 Acme AB T0M 0A0 Phone 403 546-3845 Fax 403 546-2248 Email aamlibrary@marigold.ab.ca"
```

likewise, if I try `address.match(/#{title}/)` I get nil.

Comment: Since whitespace was the root cause, consider adding that as a tag (and maybe including it in the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ruby 1.9 or higher.
It's possible that the trailing whitespace is a non-breaking space:

```
p "Relations\u00a0"  # looks like a trailing space, but strip won't remove it
```

to get rid of it:

```
"Relations\u00a0".gsub!(/^\u00a0|\u00a0$/, '')  # => "Relations"
```

A more generic solution for all unicode whitespace:

```
"Relations\u00a0".gsub!(/^[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]$/, '')  # => "Relations"
```

To see what the character is in your case:

```
title[-1].ord  # => 160 (example only)
'%x' % title[-1].ord  # => "a0" (hex equivalent; example only)
```

Comment: I used the generic solution, worked beautifully. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

`title = title[0..-2]` seemed to solve it. for some reason `strip` and `chomp` wouldn't work.

Comment: Please post how you used `strip` and `chomp`. Did you assign their return values back to the original variable? Alternatively, you can try `strip!` and `chomp!`.

Comment: I don't recommend blindly removing the last char. See my answer for why `strip` and `chomp` might not be working.